Is it possible to manually drop groups when using Spark Structured Streaming?
I am trying to build a streaming pipeline on Spark, which would have complicated sessions, being closed on a specific event.
It is advised to not use windows in this case and fallback to manual state management in flatMapGroupsWithState, so I would be able to manually remove or set a TTL for the state, when I am going to be sure that I won't need it anymore:
https://www.databricks.com/blog/2021/10/12/native-support-of-session-window-in-spark-structured-streaming.html

You may still want to leverage flatMapGroupsWithState when your business use case requires a complicated session window, for example, if the case session should also be closed on a specific type of event regardless of inactivity.

But there is also an implicit state in form of all values for the group:
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.5/sql/api/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/GroupState.scala#L42
Is there any way to remove this state as well or will it still build up unboundedly?
